# Diagonal is submanifold, Local zero set description of submanifolds.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $\Delta_M=\{(p,p)\,\vert\, p\in M\}$ be the diagonal of $M$. Then $\Delta_M$ is a submanifold of $M\times M$.
I have proved this by showing that $\mathscr{i}:M\to M\times M,\, \mathscr{i}(p)=(p,p)$ is an embedding. Otherwise it also shouldn't be difficult to show that it has the submanifold property (i.e. we have adapted coordinates at every point). However, I came across a different argument:

For $(\varphi,V)$ chart around $p\in M$ consider $f:V\times V \to \mathbb{R}^n,\,f(p,p')=\varphi(p)-\varphi(p')$ which is a submersion. Locally we then have $\Delta_M=f^{-1}(0)$ and consequently it's a submanifold of $M\times M$.

I know for a smooth map between manifolds $f:N\to M$ with constant rank on $N$ that $f^{-1}(q)$ is a closed submanifold of $M$, but I haven't figured out how this above condition is compatible. [I suspect that the argument isn't too complicated]

This is quite reminiscent of the definition of submanifolds in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and that's what leads me to believe that we have this local zero set description for submanifolds in a general way. So my question is actually more general.

Comment: what exactly is your question? You say ‘I haven’t figured out how this above condition is compatible’, but what do you mean by that? The argument shows that for each point of $\Delta_M$, there is an open neighborhood (namely $V\times V$) in $M\times M$ such that the intersection of $\Delta_M$ with that open set is equal to the level set of a submersion defined on that open set. Hence, $\Delta_M$ is a submanifold.

Comment: @peek-a-boo In that case my question becomes why you can conclude that $\Delta_M$ is a submanifold based on your second last sentence. At least I haven't encountered a submanifold description [besides for submf's of $\mathbb{R}^n$] based on level sets yet.

Comment: Then prove the following “abstract” result: let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $S\subset M$ a subset with the property that for each $p\in S$ there is an open set $U\subset M$ containing $p$ such that $S\cap U$ is a $k$-dimensional embedded submanifold of $M$. Then, $S$ is a $k$-dimensional embedded submanifold of $M$. Whatever definition of submanifold you start with (eg the slice chart condition, or any other definition you fancy) will immediately show you that being a submanifold is a ‘local property’. This really follows by unwinding definitions.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks. I'll give it a try!

Comment: oh if your issue is with level sets specifically, then google regular value theorem. It’s all based on the inverse/implicit function theorem. If you know it in $\Bbb{R}^n$, then by composing with charts, you can actually deduce the manifold version. Or simply google it/look up in any decent textbook.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Figured it out, thanks!

Comment: Even easier here: Just show that the diagonal is (in an obvious way) diffeomorphic to $M$.